# How to force ssl and www for a subdomain as an independent domain?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have own the `example.tld` .
I want to force SSL and https for `root-domain` and all of its `subdomains`.
I have used below code in `.htaccess` file of root-domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It looks work perfectly for root-domain.
But, for subdomains like as `blog.example.tld` , I have used different suggestions, such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example.\tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

But, none of them works properly, and they will redirect to ssl www version of `root-domain`, instead of ssl www version of `subdomain`.
What should I do?

Comment: To clarify, you want to always redirect to www, even for subdomains? In that case, the suggestion you have above for the “blog” subdomain should do as you require, providing you’ve put it in the correct place (although it only works for that one subdomain and you’ve incorrectly escaped the regex - but that’s not the cause of your problem) - if it’s not working then maybe you are seeing a cached response? (Easier to test with 302s)

Comment: @MrWhite - Yes, I want to always show ssl and www for domain and its subdomains.

Comment: And, I have cleared the cache, but, It doesn't work!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have found the problem.
Problem had caused by host settings.
Due to some issues, I had to define subdomain as an `independent domain` in the host. This raised issues with `Redirects`. Because, instead of subdomain, the main domain was responding to `Redirection commands`.
To solve this problem, I've transferred subdomain to another host, so `Redirection commands` for subdomain was replied from new host containing subdomain.
In this new situation, the following simple command forces `ssl and www for subdomain`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.sub.example\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I hope this experience will be useful for others.

Comment: The redirect you posted doesn't enforce `www` for the subdomain as you state?

Comment: You're right, because before this I've define HTTP_HOST as www version. I will change the code to get public usage.

Comment: "I've transferred subdomain to another host" - Yes, the directives you've posted would be OK if using a different host (or the subdomain points to a different area of the filesystem and you are able to use a different `.htaccess` file). However, they would result in a conflict if your subdomains all pointed to the same area of the filesystem as the domain apex - which I believe was the initial problem in your question?

Answer (score 3):

> But, none of them works properly, and they will redirect to ssl www version of root-domain, instead of ssl www version of subdomain.

(I'm assuming all your subdomains map to the same area of the filesystem.)

It sounds like you may have put the directives in the wrong order. If you placed the subdomain redirect *after* the root-domain redirect then it will never get processed and the root-domain redirect will catch all subdomain requests, and redirect the subdomain back to the root-domain, since the `RewriteCond` directive is checking whether the requested domain is *not* `www.example.tld` - this will also match the subdomain.

However, if you want to always enforce the www subdomain (even for your *subdomains*) then your directive(s) can be "simplified" into a single rule. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This matches any request that is either HTTP *or* does not start `www.` and redirects to HTTPS, prefixing the `www` subdomain (if necessary). The 3rd `RewriteCond` directive is necessary to capture the requested hostname, less any `www.` prefix (if any). The `%1` in the *substitution* is a backreference to the hostname, less any `www.` prefix.

This naturally affects *all* domains on the account (if you have more than one).

**UPDATE:** I've just seen your answer, so I'm not sure whether this will be relevant now or not?

Comment: Hey! You tried. Cheers!!

Comment: Well, I will test your suggestion and report the result here.

Comment: Should I use your suggested rule in `.htaccess` file of the root-domain? This rule only works when the subdomain and root-domain refer to the same filesystem? For separate filesystems, should `different rules` for domain and subdomains like as rules that I have suggested be used?

Comment: Yes, this code would go near the top of the `.htaccess` file in the document root of the "root-domain". This rule doesn't _only_ work "when the subdomain and root-domain refer to the same filesystem" as you could use/duplicate the same code for the subdomains if they point elsewhere. If the subdomains point to different filesystems/hosts then you'll need to duplicate your code. But if the subdomains point to different places then it would generally be recommended to be more specific and target the subdomain only - as you have done in your answer.

Comment: Well done! Mission completed!!